# VBA: Error using string variable with .SeriesCollection()

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

When I use the following code, I get:
  Run-time error '13':
  Type mismatch

```
Dim SeriesName as String
.
.
SeriesName = "Minor_Milestones"
.
.
.
   With .SeriesCollection(SeriesName).Points(ThisPoint)
      .
      .
```

However, if I change the one line to:

```
   With .SeriesCollection("Minor_Milestones").Points(ThisPoint)
      .
      .
```

it works fine.  Feel like I'm making a newbie mistake, but can't find it!

Comment: what if you call it this way: `With .SeriesCollection(Cstr(SeriesName)).Points(ThisPoint)`

Comment: I tried that.  It shouldn't have made a difference, since "SeriesName" was already a string, but it did.  So I thought that maybe there might be a conflict with another subroutine or reserved system name.  I changed the variable name to "zSeriesName" and that also fixed the problem!  Thanks KazJaw!

Comment: LATER NOTE: zSeriesName only worked one time.  Subsequent runs got the same error.  So I am back to KazJaw's solution without any idea of why.  But it does work. <may be better to define the variable as SeriesCollection>

Comment: Tip for you- open `Locals window` in IDE and run your sub with F8 checking the value and type of your `SeriesName variable`. Hopefully you get the point of problem. If so, you could publish the reason and solution here.

Comment: Tried that, but still can't figure it out.  It shows as a string variable type with the correct value, but still errors unless I use Cstr().